# Delete Cookie and Display Template

Tags: http, go, http-headers

I need to delete a cookie, and then display a "Logged out" page. I can't do both in one HandleFunc because, the Response is already written. Here's my code -- changing the order of renderTemplate and SetCookie doesn't help:

```
renderTemplate(w, "templates/logout.html", nil)
log.Println("Attempting to delete cookie:", app.CookieName)
http.SetCookie(w, &http.Cookie{
    Name:     app.CookieName,
    Value:    "",
    Domain:   ".example.com",
    Path:     "/",
    HttpOnly: true,
    MaxAge:   -1})
```

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Set the cookie, and then write the response.

Comment: Changing the order should fix the problem. If it does not, then confirm that the domain and path match the cookie you are trying to delete.

Comment: That worked, guess I confused myself with iterating and not keeping track of what I had tested and misunderstanding the issue. Thank you to both.

Comment: Update: It deletes the cookie, but the page is not rendered correctly because of the way nginx's auth_request gets in the way. I think. Wonder if there is a way to display the page, and then issue an Ajax request to delete the cookie (with jsQuery?) @CeriseLimón

Comment: The auth_request module returns either the response from the sub-request, or the regular response.  The module should not interfere with either of these responses.  Did you check the error from executing the template?

Comment: @CeriseLimón so what is occuring is that the template is rendered. However, because there are script includes for CSS/JS, those fail and the page looks completely broken. One simple thing, though not ideal is to just have a simple page that does no further http requests and simply says "Logged out." I'm running out of ideas here.

Comment: You can add a handler that serves "/logout" and renders the logout template. After you delete the cookie you can redirect to "/logout". Probably is gonna work

Comment: The typical approach for handling this problem is to skip authentication for static resources.

Comment: @CeriseLimón I think that's probably what I'd have to do. Except that I'm using RiceBox to embed the objects, but maybe I can tweak nginx fronting this to exclude all the *js files. Let you know.